# chemfig chemname alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, chemfig

I wish to have a reaction in `\chemfig` and write some details under each molecule so am using the `\chemname` command. It puts the text under the molecule. However, as I have arrows in the reaction scheme, the whole system is misaligned. I have tried to use the `\chemnameinit` command to set the depth of the deepest molecule (commented out in lines 6-10 of the MWE below), but to no avail. Am I missing something simple?!

I tried putting the `\arrow(){}` command within the `\chemname{}` but that spits out errors. Having the `\chemname{\chemfig{structure}{line 1\\ line2\\ line3\\ line4}}` keeps the molecules aligned (without the `\\` no alignment of molecules!)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
%\chemnameinit{\chemfig{CH_3-C(-[:90]CH_3)(-[:-90]CH_3)-{\color{blue}\lewis{0:2:6:,Cl}}}}
%\chemnameinit{\chemfig{AlCl_3}}
%\chemnameinit{\chemfig{CH_3-C(-[:90]CH_3)(-[:-90]CH_3)-\chemabove{{\color{red}\lewis{0:2:6:,Cl}}}{\pch}-Al(-[:90]Cl_3)(-[:-90]Cl_3)-Cl_3}}
%\chemnameinit{\chemfig{CH_3-\chemabove{C}{\pch}(-[:60]CH_3)(-[:-60]CH_3) }}
%\chemnameinit{\chemfig{Cl-\chemabove{Al}{\qquad\mch}(-[:90]Cl)(-[:-90]Cl)-Cl}}
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_3-C(-[:90]CH_3)(-[:-90]CH_3)-{\color{blue}\lewis{0:2:6:,Cl}}}}{Lewis Base\\ Lone pair of e$^-$\\ on Cl\\ can donate}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{AlCl_3}}{Lewis Acid\\ unfilled orbitals\\ on Al\\ Can accept e$^-$}
\arrow(--){<=>[][]}
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_3-C(-[:90]CH_3)(-[:-90]CH_3)-\chemabove{{\color{red}\lewis{0:2:6:,Cl}}}{\pch}-Al(-[:90]Cl_3)(-[:-90]Cl_3)-Cl_3}}{charged complex\\ \\ \\ }
\arrow(--){<=>[][]}
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_3-\chemabove{C}{\pch}(-[:60]CH_3)(-[:-60]CH_3) }}{Lewis Acid\\ \\ \\ }
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{Cl-\chemabove{Al}{\qquad\mch}(-[:90]Cl)(-[:-90]Cl)-Cl}}{Lewis Base\\ \\ \\ }
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image: misaligned_arrows]

Comment: Everything between two `\arrow` commands is the contents of a TikZ `\node`. The arrows align to the center of those IIRC. But you can tell them where to align by giving TikZ anchors: `\arrow(.<from anchor>--.<to anchor>)`. Alternatively you could leave all the `\chemname`s away and after drawing the scheme you could put names/descriptions under each molecule with an invisible arrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chemfig`'s `\arrow` has the optional argument `(<node1>.<anchor1>--<node2>.<anchor2>)` where both node names and anchors can be left out. In your case it is sufficient to add suitable anchor names since the baseline of the molecules all are on the same line the way you defined them. I only added (besides some indentation for readability) the anchors `base east` and `base west` and removed the superfluous `\\`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
  \chemname
    {\chemfig{CH_3-C(-[:90]CH_3)(-[:-90]CH_3)-{\color{blue}\lewis{0:2:6:,Cl}}}}
    {Lewis Base\\ Lone pair of e$^-$\\ on Cl\\ can donate}
  \+
  \chemname
    {\chemfig{AlCl_3}}
    {Lewis Acid\\ unfilled orbitals\\ on Al\\ Can accept e$^-$}
  \arrow(.base east--.base west){<=>}
  \chemname
    {%
      \chemfig{
        CH_3-C(-[:90]CH_3)(-[:-90]CH_3)
        -\chemabove{{\color{red}\lewis{0:2:6:,Cl}}}{\pch}
        -Al(-[:90]Cl_3)(-[:-90]Cl_3)-Cl_3}%
    }
    {charged complex}
  \arrow(.base east--.base west){<=>}
  \chemname
    {\chemfig{CH_3-\chemabove{C}{\pch}(-[:60]CH_3)(-[:-60]CH_3) }}
    {Lewis Acid}
  \+
  \chemname
    {\chemfig{Cl-\chemabove{Al}{\qquad\mch}(-[:90]Cl)(-[:-90]Cl)-Cl}}
    {Lewis Base}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

`chemfig`'s arrows also have an optional argument where you can specify a vertical shift:

```
\arrow(.base east--.base west){<=>[][][4pt]}
```

If I add this to the MWE above I get:

[image]

Comment: I had tried the anchor used `.east--.west` and didn't seem to work, I only saw the `.base east` anchor now on proper reading of manual. My bad...

Comment: The `chemfig` manual probably doesn't mention all anchors (I haven't checked) but they're all explained in the [pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfmanual).